# Remote uploading File from Linux terminal to Drop Zone Attachment

Tags: file-transfer, remote, upload

Actually i have the file on google colab and i need upload to site that only have a drop file zone, excuse me for not being explicit honestly i'm a noob

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The word "actually" tells us the thing BEFORE that word is NOT the same thing as what comes after. In your post here, this just begins the confusion I have trying to understand what you're asking. Please look carefully at your post and think clearly about your problem. Use the EDIT button and make your question clear and complete. Give us all of the information you have, everything you've tried, a clear description of what you need to accomplish, as well as why you need to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is: You have a website/hosting that you can only upload files using a Drop Zone (Drag and Drop) on a webpage, and you want to upload to it directly from a Linux Terminal (Google Colab.)

This is not possible in a simple way. You would need some kind of browser automation framework, like Selenium. With Selenium you should be able to do it, but it will require some scripting, you can try https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761800/5518385 or https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/22199